# SMS TWIML BIN - How to retrieve name from phone numbers?

Tags: messaging, bin, twilio-twiml

I am using this script for group notification from Twilio number 001:

```
<Response>
<Message to="+120000000007">
    {{From}}: {{Body}}
</Message>
</Response>
```

So when I send a sms from my phone to the 001, it will send a message to +120000000007

It works fine and +120000000007 get the "from" cell number +  the message I typed.

I would like the {{From}} to look up a csv file so numbers are translated into names.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a number that has called in before: 
When you look under Verified Numbers, does it show the information you are looking for?  If so, what order does it put the information in?
If it is a number that has NOT called in before:
Go into the Phone Number and enable Caller Name Lookup, save the changes, then call from that phone, does the inbound log show the information you are looking for?  If so, what order does it put the information in?
Once you know the format of the information above, you can program in PHP for Twilio to read a CSV file using fgetcsv, then parse each element within each line into an array element ($data), and look for a match.
Depending upon how many matches you are looking for, it may be more efficient to use a Case statement so you can account for the case when there is not a match.